# How to check core files in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, core-file-storage

In **Magento 1** we can check the code structure from the core files(app/code/core).

How to check the **Magento 2** core files fore coding structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Magento 1,** core files of modules are loacated at `app/code/core`

For example, **core files of catalog module** are located at

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog

**While in Magento 2,** core files of catalog module are located at

> vendor/magento/module-catalog

**In Magento 1,** core files of theme are located at app/design/frontend(adminhtml)

For example, core design files of catalog module are located at

> app/design/frontend(adminhtml)/base/default/template/catalog

**And css, js, images** are located at

> skin/frontend/base/default/(CSS, images, js)

**While in Magento 2,** all code, design, js, CSS files are located in one place

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend(adminhtml)/templates // Phtml files
>
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend(adminhtml)/layout // Layout xml files
>
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend(adminhtml)/web // Images, html, js, css
> files

Answer (score 2):

In **Magento2** you can check core files from **Vendor/Magento** then specific **module directory** and its files.

Lets say you may would like to see catalog module code then you need to located at **Vendor/Magento/module-catalog**

**Refer this link for more details** - https://darshanbhavsar.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/magento-2-directory-structure/

Answer (score 2):

1. To check the core files, you need to go `vendor/magento folder`.
2. Here can find different modules for different sections

Answer (score 2):

Core files path in Magento 2:
**vendor/magento** folder.

You can access different modules likes

- vendor/magento/module-catalog : Catalog
- vendor/magento/module-checkout : Checkout
- vendor/magento/module-cms : CMS
- vendor/magento/module-customer : Customer

And many more....

To make any changes in core file you need to copy module and follow the structure as follows:

**Layout** - app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/..... (with xmls)

**Templetes** -
 app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/..... (with phtmls)

**Block/Model/Controller** - You need to override in your Package app/code/Package/Module

Answer (score 1):

You can check your core files in vendor/magento folder in Magento 2. There are different modules for different sections like for catalog section we have module-catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Core Modules

```
/vendor/magento/
```

Code base of your custom module

```
/app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>
```

Custom theme files (storefront)

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>
```

Custom theme files (modules)

```
<Module>/<theme>
```

If you want to use a library

```
/lib/<Vendor_Library>
```